# SQLCMD or SQLPACKAGE on linux?

Tags: linux, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I am using ubuntu docker image as build agent on Azure Devops. I need to apply some DDL SQL scripts on Azure SQL DB. What tool I should use - SQLCMD or SQLPackage, or something else and why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to install SQLPackage I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15#get-sqlpackage-net-core-for-linux). It got installed, however it did not work in Azure DevOps - just loading endlessly but no error, nothing. Finally I decided to go with Python (pyodbc) to connect to SQL DB and perform certain actions - [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15), [MSSQLODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

**sqlcmd** is the widely using command line query utility to work with Azure SQL Databases or any other SQL Server.

If you run SQL Server in a Docker container, the SQL Server command-line tools are already included in the SQL Server Linux container image. If you attach to a running container with an interactive bash shell, you can run the tools locally.

The support is also good in almost all forums. So, in case if you stuck somewhere there are plenty of experienced developers across the world to help you.

You can go through official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15 for more details.

Comment: Hi @romanzdk, if you find this answer useful and it resolved your issue, please accept this as an answer (click on tick symbol on left side of the answer) to help the other community members.